# Create a random string in twig with prefix?

Tags: twig

Im trying to create a random string with twig with a set prefix eg myPrefix123. The following simply returns myPrefix:

```
  {% set randomID = 'myPrefix'|format(random(1000))  %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% set randomID = 'myPrefix' ~ random(1000) %}
```

Comment: Anyway to make the string unique ? ( need it for generating dom elements IDs with same prefix, not in a loop so I could add the index )